# NA output from sum of numbers in R

Tags: r, sum, na, func

I have a function and I get NA from `sum` function, the first `sum` works well, but the second `sum` does not work and returns `NA`.

This is the function:

```
  Gramm.Pred.Err <- function(acts , grammProbs)
  {
    acts <- as.numeric(acts)
    grammProbs <-  as.numeric(grammProbs)

    print("acts is:")
    print(acts)
    print("grammProbs is:")
    print(grammProbs)


    false.ind = grammProbs == 0
    hit.ind= grammProbs>0

    print("false.ind is:")
    print(false.ind)
    print("hit.ind is:")
    print(hit.ind)


    hit.acts = acts[hit.ind]
    hit.probs = grammProbs[hit.ind]

    print("hit.acts is:")
    print(hit.acts)
    print("hit.probs is:")
    print(hit.probs)

    misses.ind = hit.acts< hit.probs

    hits =  sum(hit.acts)

    falses =  sum( acts[false.ind])

    misses = sum( hit.probs[misses.ind] - hit.acts[misses.ind] )

    print("misses.ind is:")
    print(misses.ind)
    print("hits is:")
    print(hits)
    print("falses is:")
    print(falses)
    print("misses is:")
    print(misses)

    print("final:")
    print(1-(hits/(hits+falses+misses)))

    return (1-(hits/(hits+falses+misses)))


  }
```

acts and grammProbs vectors:

```
activations.vector <- c(  "2.08101344",  "-1.41434467",   "0.07817803",   "0.45509970",   "1.27916718",  "-0.84691423",   "2.01260424",  "-1.42960405",  "-1.47239423",
   "0.68798345",  "-0.86126810",   "1.61871290",  "-1.49541676",   "3.70249152",   "1.60749793",  "-2.68202949",   "0.58367389",  "-0.15213574",
  "9.20287609",   "1.62072563",   "4.33229876",  "-0.16497207",  "-0.16517217", "-13.28754520")

prob.vector <- c( "2.0000000", "0.0000000", "0.1666670", "0.1666670", "0.0833333", "0.0833333", "0.0833333", "0.0833333", "0.0000000", "0.0000000", "0.0833333", "0.0833333",
 "0.0000000", "0.0000000", "0.0833333", "0.0833333", "0.0000000", "0.0000000", "0.0000000", "0.0000000", "0.0000000", "0.0000000", "0.0000000", "0.0000000")
```

for these, I get the following results:

```
gpe.matrix <- matrix(, 10, 24)

gpe.matrix[1,] <- Gramm.Pred.Err(acts = activations.vector,grammProbs = prob.vector)

[1] "acts is:"
 [1]   2.08101344  -1.41434467   0.07817803   0.45509970   1.27916718  -0.84691423   2.01260424  -1.42960405  -1.47239423
[10]   0.68798345  -0.86126810   1.61871290  -1.49541676   3.70249152   1.60749793  -2.68202949   0.58367389  -0.15213574
[19]   9.20287609   1.62072563   4.33229876  -0.16497207  -0.16517217 -13.28754520
[1] "grammProbs is:"
 [1] 2.0000000 0.0000000 0.1666670 0.1666670 0.0833333 0.0833333 0.0833333 0.0833333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0833333 0.0833333
[13] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0833333 0.0833333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[25] 0.0000000
[1] "false.ind is:"
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[21]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[1] "hit.ind is:"
 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[21] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[1] "hit.acts is:"
 [1]  2.08101344  0.07817803  0.45509970  1.27916718 -0.84691423  2.01260424 -1.42960405 -0.86126810  1.61871290  1.60749793
[11] -2.68202949
[1] "hit.probs is:"
 [1] 2.0000000 0.1666670 0.1666670 0.0833333 0.0833333 0.0833333 0.0833333 0.0833333 0.0833333 0.0833333 0.0833333
[1] "misses.ind is:"
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[1] "hits is:"
[1] 3.312458
[1] "falses is:"
[1] NA
[1] "misses is:"
[1] 6.241638
[1] "final:"
[1] NA
```

Thank you so much for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

I looked through your function line by line and found the problem here:

> falses =  sum( acts[false.ind])

acts is a vector with length 24, false.ind is a vector of length 25. Therefore, the you are trying to subset a vector element which doesn't exists. This produces an NA.

If you want to have the sum of the vector without the NA you can remove the NA before summing up the vector elements like this:

> falses =  sum( acts[false.ind], na.rm = T)

Comment: Thank you so much, but why false.ind is a vector of length 25?

Comment: Im really sorry, i edited the dataset, now both of vectors have length of 24 .

Comment: Tnx Alex, the problem was the size of the Vector.